# Get file from access db with powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-access

I have an access database, now using the powershell script I connect to this access database and loop through the records and do some manipulations.

Now, one of columns contains an attachement, basically a file, how can I download/save this file locally?

Here is what I have for connection of the database and getting values from the record.

```
$cn = new-object -ComObject ADODB.Connection;
$rs =  new-object -ComObject ADODB.Recordset;

$cn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Persist Security Info = False; Data Source = $path")

$query="SELECT * FROM Table";
$rs.Open($query, $cn, 3,3);
$rs.MoveFirst();

do
{ 
    write-host $rs.Fields.Item("id").Value
    write-host $rs.Fields.Item("Column 1").Value
    write-host $rs.Fields.Item("Column 2").Value

    $rs.MoveNext();

}until($rs.EOF -eq $true)
$cn.Close();
```

So my question again, if a column contains a file, how do I handle it to save locally?

Comment: Did you try a simple `Copy-Item ($rs.Fields.Item("Column 1").Value) -Destination $env:TEMP` ?

Comment: did try now and I get an error: Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\12345\Documents\File.pptx' because
it does not exist. The name of the file retrieved from the access is atleast correct ... but yeah it tries to search it in the folder where that access is located but not In access db